# Como fazer com que a listbox seja ordenada de forma crescente?

Tags: c#, listbox

Olá!

Meu projeto em C# possui uma listbox que lista números digitados pelo usuário. O que quero fazer é que esses números sejam constantemente atualizados de forma crescente na listbox.

Tentei usar a ferramenta Sorted, mas o que acontece é: https://puu.sh/zOdxj/9ecded73c4.png

Na print: entrei com os valores 1,2,3,4,5,6 e quando entrei com o valor 11, ele apareceu logo abaixo do 1.

Código do botão Confirmar Valor:

```
if (tbNumero.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não foi digitado nenhum número.", "Erro!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                lstRoll.Items.Add(Convert.ToDouble(tbNumero.Text));                                                          
                btnRemoveRoll.Enabled = true;
                btnResetAll.Enabled = true;

                tbNumero.Text = "";
                tbNumero.Focus();
                lstRoll.Sorted = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor, digite apenas numeros", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                tbNumero.Text = "";
                tbNumero.Focus();
            }

        }
```

---

**Resolvido com esse vídeo:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKu3m1NwrUU

Comment: Os elementos estão ordenados como texto que é o que foi armazenado na `ListBox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mesmo que você tenha convertido o texto para o tipo `Double`, antes de adicionar o valor ao `ListBox`:

```
lstRoll.Items.Add(Convert.ToDouble(tbNumero.Text));
```

a classificação no controle `ListBox` é sempre feita de forma alfabética, tratando os itens como se fossem do tipo `String`:

> ListBox.Sorted Property
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted.aspx

Você pode, então, jogar a lista de valores para um array, classifica-los lá e devolver a lista classificada, numericamente, para o `ListBox`:

```
// Cria um array de doubles com a mesma quantidade de itens que o ListBox.
double[] arrayNumerico = new double[lstRoll.Items.Count];
// Copia a lista de itens para o array de doubles.
((ICollection)lstRoll.Items).CopyTo(arrayNumerico, 0);
// Classifica o array de doubles, de forma numérica.
Array.Sort(arrayNumerico);
// Limpa o conteúdo do ListBox e adiciona os itens do array, classificados numericamente.
lstRoll.SetItemsCore(arrayNumerico);
```

**EDIT:**
Não tinha reparado que o escopo do método `ListBox.SetItemsCore()` é `Protected`, então não dará para usa-lo diretamente. No lugar dele (a última linha do código) você pode fazer assim, então:

```
lstRoll.Items.Clear();
lstRoll.Items.AddRange((object[])arrayNumerico);
```

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado!
Tenho mais uma dúvida:

Como faço para selecionar o primeiro valor da listbox?

Preciso fazer (último valor) - (primeiro valor) para guardar numa variável, mas não sei a sintaxe.

Comment: Você pode fazer assim para pegar o primeiro item `lstRoll.Items[0]`, e assim para pegar o último `lstRoll.Items[lstRoll.Items.Count-1]`.